# Full-featured Windows XMPP client that supports message carbons, archive management, and file upload

Tags: windows, xmpp

I'm looking for a Windows XMPP client with the following features:

- Message carbons (XEP-280)
- Message archive management (XEP-313)
- Avatars (XEP-84)
- File upload (XEP-363), preferably with previews on images/where applicable
- Installable as a standalone program (not web-based)

And finally, although not nearly as important, I'd like for it to look nice. I will gladly take a client that doesn't meet this requirement though.

Comment: You should probably say which version of windows you're on

Answer (score 1):

[**Gajim**](https://gajim.org/) ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gajim)) is a free/libre XMPP client. It exists since 2004 and is still maintained.

It’s available for BSD, GNU/Linux, and [Windows](https://gajim.org/downloads.php#windows). I’m using it as my primary XMPP client on GNU/Linux. I tested it on a Windows system once and everything seemed to work fine there, too.

It [supports](https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim/wikis/help/GajimXEPSupport):

- [XEP-0280: Message Carbons](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280)
- [XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313)
- [XEP-0363: HTTP File Upload](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0363)

It doesn’t seem to support XEP-0084, but it supports avatars based on [XEP-0153: vCard-Based Avatars](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153).

You can find some [screenshots on the official website](https://gajim.org/screenshots.php), e.g.:

> [image: Gajim: roster] 
>   [image: Gajim: tabbed chat windows]

There is also a mode where the roster window and the chat window are combined into one window. I made a screenshot of my client (sorry, it’s in German and taken on GNU/Linux):

[image: Gajim: combined window]

(On the left is the list of my accounts. Each account entry can be expanded to list its groups/contacts. On the bottom I can change the status. If chatting with multiple contacts, each chat is displayed as a tab.)

It comes with a few alternative themes and icon sets.

Answer (score 0):

I've stopped using XMPP after one server I used shut down and the other went flaky.  But I used to use [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) mainly because I was familiar with it from Linux (it's cross-platform). It certainly supports requirements 3--5 of your list.  My recollection is that you have archiving and some control over it but I could be flat-out wrong there, and whether it's *enough* control I don't know (I mainly used google's talk server which was XMPP-based before they tried to push everyone onto hangouts, and the server did things its own way especiallty regarding archiving). I'm not sure about carbons, partly as I'm not exactly sure what you mean.